Features of archimesh walls
I'm starting to studing achitectural modeling and after watching some tutorials, some people uses regular polygons to make the walls and some others uses Archimesh add-on
I can see how others components like doors, rail windows, stairs speeds up a lot the workflow for modeling a home for instance, but still couldn't see the benefits of using the walls of archimesh comparing to a regular mesh.
What are the advantages of using archimesh walls comparing to just take a mesh and model it upon the floor plan?
